# Xamarin Portal Class Library Access ASP.NET Web ApiController

Tags: android, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to create a PCL that will be able to be reused across Android, iOS, and Windows Phone with Xamarin.  The core of the class library will be used to communicate with an ASP.NET Web ApiController hosted on Windows Azure.  I'm having a really hard time getting the HttpClient to work.  Here is the code.

```
        public async Task<string> GetData()
    {
        string responseStr = null;

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myapi.com/");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var data = new { data1 = "1", data2 = "2" };
            var content = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            StringContent httpContent = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("Events/GetData", httpContent);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
        return responseStr;
    }
```

If I use this code in a Console app it works flawlessly but when I try and do the same thing in a PCL while debugging an Android app it gets to the `await httpClient.PostAsyc` line, sits for a second or two and then immediately jumps down to the end of the method never returning and never throwing an exception.

I have no idea what is going on and have no idea why this would work in a console app but not in the PCL.  I have referenced the necessary HTTP Client Libraries in both the Android project and in the PCL.

End of the day, I just need a solution that allows me to post to an Web ApiController and read the data back.  I have tried a number of solutions and none seem to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

await should return Task. Capture object of Task type and check Exception and Status properties instead to convert direct to HttpResponseMessage (response) and string responseStr in Your case.

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = await httpClient.PostAsync("Events/GetData", httpContent);
// response.Exception
// repsonse.Status
```

and

```
Task<string> responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
// responseStr.Exception
// responseStr.Status
```

This way You'll get more info about what is going on. Some platforms like iOS might refuse connection to servers w/o valid certificates and similar.

further refs:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx